# Search in a join query via list

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I would like to extract those records from a join linq query which exist in a list, clearly i have these data

lst_Unique
table_Prt
table_Exp

but my query does not work

```
var Query = from c in db.table_Exp join d in db.table_Prt
on c.PrId equals d.PrId
.Where( t=> lst_Unique.Contains(t.PrId))
select new {c.Name,d.Code,d.Age} ;
```

How can i fix it? Actually there is a problem in "where" statement.
Thanks for help

Comment: what you mean by does not work?

Answer (score 4):

You can't mix query syntax and method syntax like this, a query syntax should always end with a `select` or `groupby` clause.

If I have understood you correctly, then this is what you want:-

```
var Query = from c in db.table_Exp join d in db.table_Prt
            on c.PrId equals d.UniprotID
            where lst_Unique.Contains(c.PrId)
            select new {c.Name,d.Code,d.Age} ;
```

Here, I have considered that you wanna match `Id` property of `table_Exp` table with unique list, but you need to change that accordingly as per your requirement.

Comment: Please consider **both tables have a field names PrId**. Your query does not work, error shows **string does not contains PrId**. In **Where** statement we don't  allow to use **t.PrId** .

Comment: @user3616494 - Check my update, I had considered `lst_Unique` to be a custom list but it must be a `List<String>` as per your comment, check this and it should work.

Comment: Thanks @Rahul Singh for your help and it still does not work. I used List<string> but shows another error **Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementation of query operators except the Contains() operator.**

Comment: @user3616494 - Check my update, use `Contains` instead of `Any` as you can't do that operation with SQL source & local source.

Answer (score -1):

Remove "." before Where in your Query.

```
var Query = from c in db.table_Exp join d in db.table_Prt
on c.PrId equals d.UniprotID
Where( t=> lst_Unique.Contains(t.PrId))
select new {c.Name,d.Code,d.Age} ;
```